# Does using ASCII transfer mode in FTP while transferring files from one linux based system to other linux based system changes LF to CRLF

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, ascii

Whether using ASCII transfer mode in FTP while transferring files from one linux based system to other linux based system changes LF to CRLF

Comment: Right, that's exactly how it works as documented in the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt).  `End-of-Line: The end-of-line sequence defines the separation of printing lines.  The sequence is Carriage Return, followed by Line Feed.`  Did you have a question?

Comment: That conversion from LF to CRLF is not happening and my questions is what would be the root cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a ASCII based transfer will allow the receiver of the files to dictate what the line terminator character(s) is when storing the file.  Thus a transfer from linux->linux should leave line terminators the same....BUT a transfer from linux-->Windows will translate a \n to a \r\n terminator.